# Mechanical wave transmission through 3 strings of different medium qualities

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, string, many-body

How would the motion of waves behave if there are 3 strings joined to each other (as displayed in the fig.) and a wave was started in the string-3? Which would undergo inversion of strings and for what reason?
[image]

**Description:** The fig. indicates the velocities $$\ v_1,v_2,v_3$$ in strings 3,1,2 respectively. The relation $$\ v_3<v_1<v_2$$ implies that the masses of the strings follow the relation 2>3>1.
Also, is such a scenario possible for light?

[Apologies for the inconveniences in the numerical subscripts]

Comment: I don't think the relation between the masses or to be specific the mass densities are correct

Comment: @ChayankaKakati Yes, I suppose so. I've made the required edit. I think it should be right now.

Comment: still looks wrong--the velocities' numbers should correspond to string numbers